# lighttpd mod_secdownload always 404's

Tags: lighttpd

I'm trying to set up expiring urls for my company's dev environment. We use `lighttpd` to serve uploaded files in this environment, and I found [these docs](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSecDownload) which seem fairly promising.

The problem is I can't seem to get it to work at all, and I'm sort of at my wits end trying to figure out why. It serves paths under the `secdownload.uri-prefix` normally, as if they were unprotected files under the normal `server.document root`.

Here is my entire config file:

```
server.modules = (
    "mod_secdownload"
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 8080

secdownload.secret           = "seecrat"
secdownload.document-root    = "/var/www/download-area/"
secdownload.algorithm        = "md5"
secdownload.uri-prefix       = "/dl/"

debug.log-request-handling  = "enable"
```

Here is a snippet of JS that's creating the urls from Node.js:

```js
const md5 = require("md5");
const filePath = "/some-image.png";
const timestamp = Date.now().toString(16);
const signature = md5("seecrat" + filePath + timestamp);
console.log(`http://localhost:8080/dl/${signature}/${timestamp}${filePath}`);
```

Here's an example url generated by this code:

```
http://localhost:8080/dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png
```

When I navigate to this URL in by browser, I get a 404 Not Found, and the debug log for this request looks like this:

```
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.447) -- splitting Request-URI 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.448) Request-URI     :  /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.449) URI-scheme      :  http 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.450) URI-authority   :  localhost:8080 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.451) URI-path (raw)  :  /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.452) URI-path (clean):  /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.453) URI-query       :   
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.598) -- before doc_root 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.599) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.600) Rel-Path     : /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.601) Path         :  
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.643) -- after doc_root 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.644) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.645) Rel-Path     : /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.646) Path         : /var/www/html/dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.670) -- logical -> physical 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.671) Doc-Root     : /var/www/html 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.672) Basedir      : /var/www/html 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.673) Rel-Path     : /dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.674) Path         : /var/www/html/dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.686) -- handling physical path 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.687) Path         : /var/www/html/dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.162) -- file not found 
2020-11-23 14:03:02: (response.c.163) Path         : /var/www/html/dl/5fe360f8c62ea912363b653ba9383e01/175f67cd240/some-image.png
```

Clearly, it is looking under `/var/www/html` instead of `/var/www/download-area` as expected.

EDIT:

This question has been edited for clarity. I removed unrelated stuff from my config and added a debug log from the request handler.

Answer (score 0):

> secdownload.uri-prefix       = "/dl/"

> const filePath = "/some-image.png";

These do not match.  I think you mean `const filePath = "/dl/some-image.png";`

There are many examples available in different programming languages in the [mod_secdownload](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSecDownload) docs to which you linked.

If mod_secdownload intercepts all requests to /dl/*, then the files that would otherwise be accessible under /dl/* are protected.  On the other hand, if I can directly request /some-image.png from your server, bypassing /dl/... and mod_secdownload, then /some-image.png is not very well protected.

[Edit] Is some-image.png found under /var/www/html/some-image.png?  (With your config `secdownload.document-root = "/var/www/html/"`)

Comment: `filePath` here serves the same purpose as `rel_path` in their examples. It is the portion of the path which locates the file relative to the document root, and should therefore not include the uri prefix.

Comment: You are exactly right that everything under the /dl/* path should be protected-- that is the whole point , after all-- but after the /dl/ path comes the digital signature token, the timestamp, and *then* the file path. The docs make this abundantly clear. Like, I'm willing to accept the possiblity that I'm just doing something wrong, but this isn't it. :\

Comment: Have you tried any of the many examples in the [mod_secdownload](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModSecDownload) documentation?

Comment: Is some-image.png located under /var/www/html/some-image.png ? ( `secdownload.document-root    = "/var/www/html/"`)

Comment: Yes. Again, the problem seems to be that the module isn't active at all, despite being in my server.modules list.

Comment: `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p` to see what lighttpd parses for the complete config.

Comment: `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -tt` to pre-flight the config.  Look if there are any errors or warning.   Please also verify that you are actually stopping and starting lighttpd to pick up your config changes, and are connecting to the IP addr and port on which your config is running.

Comment: You can modify lighttpd.conf to provide some additionally logging: (may be noisy) [lighttpd debug variables](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/DebugVariables)

Comment: Please note that the lighttpd test suite includes tests for mod_secdownload, so you can review `tests/mod-secdownload.conf` and `tests/mod-secdownload.t` in the [lighttpd source tree](https://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd1.4.git/)

Comment: @sripberger did you try any of the above?

Comment: Yes. I tried most of that before even making the question. Though I haven't tried the debug variables yet. I'll give that a shot today.

Comment: Gave it a shot, and it is indeed serving paths under the secdownload.uri-prefix normally, as I suspected. I'm going to give this a shot on a MacOS machine (most of our developers work in MacOS) later today and maybe I'll see different behavior. But if you have any other troubleshooting tips I'm happy to try them out.

Comment: Seeing pretty much the same behavior on MacOS. Definitely has to be something I'm missing, I guess?

Comment: "Definitely has to be something I'm missing, I guess?"  Yes, it must.  I am a lighttpd developer, and I have pointed you to the test programs in the lighttpd source tree which test the functionality which you claim is not working, ergo you must be doing something differently.  On Mac OS 11, when I build lighttpd from source and run `make check`, the tests pass, including `tests/mod-secdownload.t`